# HTML button element to toggle CSS overflow on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

As the title states I want to create a button which enables/disables overflow:hidden in the page. and the default stance should be that the overflow:hidden is active and the page cant be scrolled.

I looked around for something similiar, didnt find anything.

EDIT:

Ok heres what I did with your help, having trouble linking the function to a button. I might be miss understading something cause my skills in html and Jquery are limited.

After some research i got it to work by making the selector select an id and i gave the button and id.

```
    $(function (){
   $("#buttoni").on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
   });
});
```

and the button:

```
<button id="buttoni"> toggle scroll</button>
```

And that way i got it to work, im not sure what i missunderstood in the original to not get it to work but THANKS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow... please post your related code with the questions...please go through the link http://stackoverflow.com/faq.. your question is more likely to get closed.. if you don't provide some codes or things you have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about

```
.no-scroll{
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

and apply it to `body`

```
<body class="no-scroll">
```

and with jquery toggle it

```
$(function(){
   $('buttonid').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
   });
});
```

Comment: Where could I post the whole index code i have, its quite long. Are there site where it can be saved and linked here or so on?

Comment: @Fruktoosi, you can use http://jsfiddle.net to create a *live* version of your code